# Get Last Entry in Row in SQL Table

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I'm have an HTTP servlet in Java using JDBC and I need to extract information on a single row in an SQL table. The row looks like this:

```
{"dologin":false,"close":false,"due":"2016-12-12 10:00:00.5","timezone":"Pacific\/Honolulu","penalty_time":"86400","penalty_cost":"0.2","code":"anotherCode"}
```

I want to get the string after "code" (which in this case would be "anotherCode"). How do I do that?

Comment: do you have an id `auto_increment` or `datetime` column for `order by xxx DESC limit 1` ?

Comment: No I don't have that column

Comment: ah I see last entry in row, I read it as last entry in last row, sorry

Answer (score 0):

try this

Consider it as an json object

```
var json_data={"dologin":false,"close":false,"due":"2016-12-12 10:00:00.5","timezone":"Pacific\/Honolulu","penalty_time":"86400","penalty_cost":"0.2","code":"anotherCode"}
```

then

```
var some_string=json_data[ Object.keys(obj).sort().pop() ];
```

we get the last one by using the `Object.keys`

Comment: So I have it as a string in my code, already using codeRS.getString("settings") where 'codeRS' was the result set from the original query "SELECT settings FROM lti_link" and 'settings' is a column of the table 'lti_link.' How do I get the result in the form of a json structure in Java?